# Why jPlayer video are not playing?

Tags: javascript, php, html, flash, jplayer

```
        $("#jPlayer").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    flv: 'http://st1.blive.kg/storage/flv7/2/249162.70951.flv'
                });
            },
            swfPath: "/js/Jplayer.swf",
            supplied: "flv"
        }).jPlayer("play");
```

Whats wrong with my code?***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$("#jPlayer").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            flv: 'http://st1.blive.kg/storage/flv7/2/249162.70951.flv'
        });

        $(this).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "/js/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "flv"
});
```